# How to import Heroku application database locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed one rails application at Heroku. Now, I want to copy the production database to local machine for analyzing. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The heroku [pg-extras](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras) plugin makes this pretty straightforward.

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE localdbname --app myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

First, tell Heroku to capture a new backup:

```
heroku pg:backups capture
```

Then retrieve the backup from Heroku:

```
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url`
```

Now import latest.dump into your local database (replace myuser and mydb) with the name of your postgres user account and name of your local database:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```

Comment: After Running heroku pg:backups capture When i ran curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url It says 'curl' is not recognized command. I am using window platform